# Tab performance in cn1

Tags: codenameone

The tab in cn1 works pretty good. But it could be better. I've 2 tabs. When I am in left tab, its content should not move when swiped from left. If it is swiped right, the right tab appears which is fine. Again if I swipe from right in the right tab, its content should not move since there's no other tab in its right. 
One more thing, the movements of tabs are not smooth enough. It stops a bit before new tab appears completely.

Have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/e0TnfSVLSoA)

Answer (score 0):

Tabs display iOS style tensile behavior by default. They let you swipe to an area where you have "nothing" so you can see it's empty. If they just blocked that motion you wouldn't know there is nothing there in the hidden tabs mode.

Comment: I don't see that effect in android. If there is side menu as well then its a bit cumbersome. Is there a way to stop that tensile behavior?

Comment: Our tab swipe code predated Androids ability to swipe tabs. It hasn't changed much since it was introduced. There is no way to disable that but I would doubt you would want to do that. You would probably want to draw the tensile highlight from Android indicating there is nowhere to swipe to. That would require some changes to Tabs.java that aren't trivial

Comment: ok I've tested other apps in iOS, they dont move too much as in cn1. Almost perfect horizontal movement only drag the tab but in cn1, the tab moves too much.  While scrolling the components vertically in a tab, the other tab component seems to be dragged which is annoying. Can I adjust that?

Comment: There is no setting for that. Most of our customers disable swiping altogether to prevent accidental side swipes. Limiting the tensile depth would probably be easier to accomplish. When this was implemented originally neither iOS nor Android supported tab swiping...

Comment: The screen moves diagonally. That is my main issue. Please see the video https://youtu.be/1GyEOGoMPVI If that could be adjusted, it'd be nice

Comment: The only workaround I can offer at this time is to disable side swiping using `setSwipeActivated(false)`